# On opening Excel, it keeps prompting me that a custom add-in cannot be found. How can I stop this?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Whenever I open Excel, it tells me that a particular custom add-in cannot be found. I no longer needed this custom add-in and have deleted it from my computer. How can I stop excel from continuously prompting me with this error?

[image]

As a solution, I went:

Developer > Excel Add-Ins > Clicked on the Add-In (which had a tick next to it's name) > I was prompted, "Cannot find add-in 'E:...xlam'. Delete from list?", I clicked "Yes" > I then click "Ok" to close out of the Add-ins.

After doing this and restarting Excel, it still prompts me with the exact same message.

Are there solutions to this? I have removed about 3 or so excel add-ins, so it's becoming annoying having to click ok 3 times every time I open Excel.

Comment: Please specify the exact Excel version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How can I stop excel from continuously prompting me with this error?

As follows:

> First you will want to note the file path that Excel thinks the add-in
> should be located in and the name of the add-in file. Once you know
> where that folder is located and the name of the add-in, proceed to do
> the following:
>
> 1. Create a new Excel file
> 2. Save the file with the following conditions:
>
>    Use the Add-in name
>
>    Use the Excel file extension “.xlam” (if it is an older add-in it might need to be “.xla”)
>
>    Save to the same folder path
> 3. Once you have saved this new faux add-in file, close down Excel
> 4. Reopen Excel and hopefully you won’t receive the error message
> 5. Go into your Excel Add-ins dialog box and check the add-in and hit Ok
> 6. Go back into you Excel Add-ins dialog box and uncheck the add-in and hit OK
> 7. Close out of Excel

Source: [How To Prevent The Excel Error Message For A Missing Add-in](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/prevent-excel-error-message-for-missing-add-in)

Answer (score 0):

See if deleting the Add-In via the registry helps. Start the Registry Editor (regedit.exe) and go to:

*For Office 365 (with latest updates), check this registry key:*

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Add-in Manager

If you're running an older version of Excel, click on the corresponding subkey under `"Microsoft\Office\<version>"`

Backup the key by exporting it to a REG file.

In the right pane, select the Add-In you want to delete and press Del.